# SSL error on Magento 2 Sign In for marketplace

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have configured a basic install of Magento 2 with a theme for a client.

Magento is running on IIS and Windows. (Not WAMP), shared IIS hosting on windows (My own server).

I configured the shop to use SSL, and the complete shop runs over SSL without any issues.

However, when trying to use the market place, I get a weird SSL issue: "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" This error is shown on the Magneto shop (which is currently running over ssl), when trying to sign in to the market place.

[image]

I have found lots of hits on this issue, but all answers seem to lead to a self-signed certificate that isn't trusted or adding intermediary and/or root certificates. This is all based on XAMP, WAMP or native 'nix installations.

I do not understand what the exact issue is. I also do not know how to troubleshoot this further as the error description is very vague.

I would appreciate some feedback.

Thanks